# How to send FormData In Http Post using Spray

Tags: scala, http, spray, form-data

I want with my Spray Client Send a post Request with this Content Type

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

I belive that i need to use the object FormData for it :

```
var fD = new FormData(Seq("UserID:" -> "123", "PWD" -> "123" , "Brand" -> "123"))
```

But i'm open for other solutions to .

Edit :

I tried sending it this way :

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("Client")
  var fD =  FormData(Map("UserID" -> "123", "PWD" -> "123" , "Brand" -> "123"))
  import system.dispatcher // execution context for futures below
  val log = Logging(system, getClass)
  log.info("Sending test Msg")
  val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[FormData]
  var startTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
  val responseFuture = pipeline {
    Post(url, fD)
  }
  responseFuture.onComplete(x=> println(s"Request completed in ${System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimestamp} millis.\n" +
    s"Recived :"+x.get)

  )
```

And I'm Getting this error :

```
spray.httpx.PipelineException: UnsupportedContentType(Expected 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

What I'm Done Wrong ? Thank to helpers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've basically answered your own question -- you'll want to stick with FormData.  A couple of minor things though:

1. Since you're using the FormData case class, you can drop the
   "new".
2. The companion object for FormData will allow you to pass in
   a Map instead of a Seq of tuples.

Comment: I now edited and added the code i tried and im getting UnsupportedCOntentType Exeption . Maybe You know what to do ?

Comment: That exception is likely being thrown because of `unmarshal[FormData]`.  The unmarshaller is expecting that the response will contain a Content-Type header of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, when it in fact doesn't. Try changing to `unmarshal[HttpResponse]`